# cant update ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, filezilla

Hi i am trying to update the ubuntu 16.04 it's showing the following error

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/programs-ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/programs-ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

i cant install filezilla without fix this error. i have tried all the solution but it's give's me the same error please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PPA in your question [does not provide packages for xenial](https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/programs-ppa).
You should remove it.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:n-muench/programs-ppa
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:n-muench/programs-ppa
```

Also understanding how PPA works may help - see ["What are PPAs and how do I use them?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

Comment: i cant install the filezilla it's shows Depends: filezilla-common but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libfilezilla0 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libpugixml1v5 (>=1.7) but it is not installable
 Depends: libwxbase3.0-0v5 (>=3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
 Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>=3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not installable

Comment: Try `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install filezilla`.

Comment: great its working